# Add information to input - alternative for TouchDevice in UWP?

Tags: c#, wpf, uwp, uwp-xaml

I want to add more information to Touches/MouseClicks etc. on my UWP app.
In WPF one can use the TouchDevice class, inherit from it and extend it:

```
public class MyTouchDevice : TouchDevice
{
    public override GetTouchPoint(IInputElement relativeTo)...
    }
    ...
```

add the class to the input messaging system:

```
MyTouchDevice device = new MyTouchDevice(...);
device.Activate();
```

and use it:

```
private void OnTouchDown(object sender, TouchEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.TouchDevice is MyTouchDevice)
    {
    ...
```

How can I do this in an UWP app? There is no `TouchDevice` and `PointerDevice` is something completely different. In addition to that, nearly every class (`PointerPoint`, `Pointer`, etc.) is sealed.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid no such APIs are available in UWP, but you can try to use [UIViewSettings.GetForCurrentView | getForCurrentView method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.viewmanagement.uiviewsettings.getforcurrentview.aspx) to detect the current interaction mode and then maybe do your work:

```
switch (UIViewSettings.GetForCurrentView().UserInteractionMode)
{
    case UserInteractionMode.Mouse:
        //TODO:
        break;

    case UserInteractionMode.Touch:
    default:
        //TODO:
        break;
}
```

If this doesn't help, my suggestion is you may submit a request to add this new features for developing through the Windows Feedback tool.